# Python float precision with no integer precision after decimal point

Tags: python, floating-point

While working with float precision, I stumbled across a strange fact. Why does python prints only the integer part when formatted with `"%.f"`. I am willing to know the mechanism behind this

```
 >>> a = float(2.12345)
 >>> a
 2.12345
 >>> print "%.2f" % a
 2.12
 >>> print "%.1f" % a
 2.1
 >>> print "%f" % a
 2.123450
 >>> print "%.f" % a
 2                   #why?
```

Thanks in advance for the explanation :)

Comment: Because `"%.f"` is the same as `"%.0f"`?

Comment: For the same reason that `1.0` is the same as `1.`, probably.

Comment: This appears to be undefined behaviour. The optional precision is [given as a `'.'` (dot) followed by the precision](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations). The [format specification mini-language documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) similarly requires an argument for the precision. Since `int()` returns 0 it seems like a reasonable default, but undefined behaviour means exactly that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been that way [ever since `%` formatting was added back in 1993](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/7116ecb7b4f20aaf3503c9a6ba497217c9b3c7e3); if a `.` is not followed by a decimal number then [precision is taken as zero](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7116ecb7b4f20aaf3503c9a6ba497217c9b3c7e3/Objects/stringobject.c#L557).

This is undocumented, but is consistent with [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf), which Python's `%` formatting was inspired by:

> (optional) `.` followed by integer number or `*`, or neither that specifies precision of the conversion. In the case when `*` is used, the precision is specified by an additional argument of type int. If the value of this argument is negative, it is ignored. If neither a number nor `*` is used, the precision is taken as zero.

Interestingly, another undocumented feature also inspired by `printf` is that you can use `*` as precision, as above:

```
>>> "%6.*f" % (2, 1.234)
'  1.23'
```

Comment: your answer seems logical to me. But I wonder why the string format raises value error as mentioned by srowland in his answer?

Comment: @HiteshPaul `string.format` is a later API (introduced in PEP 3101) so it was possible to have it conform strictly to the specification; the undocumented behavior of `%` couldn't be removed without breaking backward compatibility.

Comment: @HiteshPaul See my answer below :)

Answer (score 1):

The docs for precision [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#grammar-token-precision) don't mention a default if the precision is ommitted. I can only assume it just works this way because it does!

The docs give the default precision for a %f as 6 in the format specification mini language [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language). Maybe by specifying a precision with the . and then by omitting an integer value, the interpreter assumes it should be zero?

This may even behave differently on different interpreters. Interesting find anyway :).

Interestingly, using str.format throws a nice ValueError in my 2.7 interpreter:

```
>>> f = 234.12345676
>>> "{:.f}".format(f)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Format specifier missing precision
```

Comment: It seems weird though, python raises ValueError for string format and none for '%'  format.

Comment: Completely agree with you :). I guess format has a more rigorous implementation on this point.

Comment: so does that mean the internal implementation differs for string format and % format?

Comment: I don't think either result is more "rigorous".  As I said in a comment on the question, this is undefined behaviour. You might get a default of zero decimal points, you might get an exception, the Python interpreter might crash, or your machine might reboot. Some options seem better choices, but all are valid.

Comment: Thanks @Chris - link fixed. And I agree this is just undefined. It is probably a little more user friendly that `format` gives a `ValueError` in my interpreter whereas `"%.f"` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

The `%` operator has the following behavior, like you observed:

```
>>> "%.f" % 1.23
'1'
```

The parser goes through the format string, with the precision being [undefined (`-1`) by default](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.3/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L13548). When it hits the `.`, the precision [will be set to `0`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.3/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L13656). The arguments will be passed to the [helper function `formatfloat`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.3/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L13285) which uses the default precision `6` if no precision is given, and no `.` is used.

An interesting note is that [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) will actually [throw an exception](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.3/Python/formatter_unicode.c#L235) in this case, probably for easier implementation and not letting people rely on unspecified behavior:

```
>>> "{:.f}".format(1.23)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-6-677ba2e4a680>", line 1, in <module>
    "{:.f}".format(1.23)
ValueError: Format specifier missing precision
```